# Invalid syntax on EmberJS Octane observers

Tags: ember.js, ember-octane

I'm trying to use Ember observers with EmberJS Octane latest version (4.1.0), but it does not seem to work.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve :

```js
export default class SummaryService extends Service {
  @service store;
  @service authentication;

  @reads('authentication.userId') userId;

  @tracked weekPosts;
  @tracked monthPosts;

  @observer('userId')
  loadPosts() {
    this._loadPosts(this.userId);
  }

  _loadPosts(userId) {
    this.store.query('posts', { filter: { 'current-week': 1, 'user-id': userId } })
      .then((posts) => {
        this.set('weekPosts', posts);
      });
    this.store.query('posts', { filter: { 'current-month': 1, 'user-id': userId } })
      .then((posts) => {
        this.set('monthPosts', posts);
      });
  }
}
```

=> The syntax is invalid.

I also tried :

```js
@observer('userId', function() {
  this._loadPosts();
});
```

=> The observer is indeed called, but `this` is undefined.

I also tried :

```js
  init() {
    super.init(...arguments);
    this.addObserver('currentUserId', this, '_loadPosts');
  }
```

=> But this one does not call any method (even with inline method definition).

Finally, my last attempt was to use `@computed` properties for `weekPosts` and `monthPosts` instead, like this :

```js
export default class SummaryService extends Service {
  /* ... */

  @computed('userId')
  get weekPosts() {
    return this.store.query('posts', { filter: { 'current-week': 1 } })
      .then((posts) => { return posts; });
  }
}
```

=> But it always returns a `Promise`, so I can't call `.reduce` on it from a computed property used by a `Component` :

```js
export default class SummaryComponent extends Component {
  @computed('weekPosts')
  get weekPostsViewsCount() {
    return this.weekPosts.reduce((sum, post) => { return sum + post.viewCount });
  }
}
```

I finally got something working pretty ugly using an `ArrayProxy.extend(PromiseProxyMixin)` returned by the `weekPosts` computed property, but I'm definitely not happy with this for the following reasons :

1. So much code for such a simple thing
2. Everything (component, template) which uses the `weekPosts` has to make sure the promise is fulfilled before working with it
3. The promise is an implementation detail of the service and should not be visible in any way out of it

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observers won't work for what you want to do -- since it looks like you want to reactively re-fetch data (using ember-data) based on when `userId` changes, I have a library suggestion:

- https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-data-resources

With this library, we can replace most of your service with this:

```js
import { query } from 'ember-data-resources';

export default class SummaryService extends Service {
  @service authentication;

  @reads('authentication.userId') userId;

  _weekPosts = query(this, 'posts', () => ({
    filter: { 'current-week': 1, 'user-id': this.userId 
  }));

  _monthPosts = query(this, 'posts', () => ({
    filter: { 'current-month': 1, 'user-id': this.userId 
  }));

  get weekPosts() {
    return this._weekPosts.records ?? [];
  }

  get monthPosts() {
    return this._monthPosts.records ?? [];
  }

  get isLoading() {
    return this._weekPosts.isLoading || this._monthPosts.isLoading;
  }

}
```

The advantage here is that you also have the ability to manage error/loading/etc states.

This uses a technique / pattern called "Derived state", where instead of performing actions, or reacting to changes, or interacting withe lifecycles, you instead define how data is *derived* from other data.

In this case, we have known data, the `userId`, and we want to *derive* queries, using `query` from ember-data-resources, also uses derived state to provide [the following api](https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-data-resources#query):

- `this._weekPosts`

  - `.records`
  - `.error`
  - `.isLoading`
  - `.isSuccess`
  - `.isError`
  - `.hasRun`

Which then allows you to define other `get`ters which derive data, `weekPosts`, `isLoading`, etc.

Derived state is much easier to debug than observer code -- *and* it's lazy, so if you don't access data/getters/etc, that data is not calculated.

Comment: Thank you ! I definitely prefer to avoid this kind of dependencies so I achieved something similar by creating a simple new class : `PromiseProxyObject = EmberObject.extend(PromiseProxyMixin)`. The use of it is almost the same as the library : `@computed('userId') get _weekEntries() { return PromiseProxyObject.create({ promise: myStoreQuery }); }` and then `@reads('_weekEntries.content') weekEntries`. This class has almost the same API as your library, given by the EmberJS`PromiseProxy` (`isFulfilled`, `isRejected`, `reason`, ...)

Comment: noice! clever! 

That's "pretty much" what I did *in another library* here: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-computed-promise-monitor/blob/master/addon/utils/promise-monitor.ts